# How to rename only folders?

Tags: file-handling, python-3.9

I have a folder that looks much like this though with many more files and folders:

[image]

and I want to rename all folders starting with `00` to add the prefix `540-` without changing any other file types. So far I've got:

[image]

However while this leaves any files not starting `0` it renames all the `.txt` files and any `.dwg` files that would start with `00`.

Is there any easy way of removing all but the folders?

Comment: Please, avoid [posting images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). It is a better practice to transcribe them instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) and your code will be a lot more readable and easier:

```py
from pathlib import Path

folder = Path('TEST-540')

for o in folder.glob('00*'):
    if o.is_dir():
        o.rename(f'540-{o.name}')
```